# What's the complexity of for i: for o = i+1

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

```
for i = 0 to size(arr)
   for o = i + 1 to size(arr)
      do stuff here
```

What's the worst-time complexity of this? It's not N^2, because the second one decreases by one every i loop. It's not N, it should be bigger. N-1 + N-2 + N-3 + ... + N-N+1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It **is** `N ^ 2`, since it's the product of two linear complexities.

(There's a reason asymptotic complexity is called **asymptotic** and not **identical**...)

See [Wikipedia's explanation on the simplifications made](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example).

Comment: @evening what "operations"?

Comment: @evening:  Think n(n-1), which expands to n^2-n, which is O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like you are working with a n x n matrix.  You are approximately working on half of the elements in the matrix, but O(n^2/2) is the same as O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

It's `n*(n-1)/2` which is equal to `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to determine the complexity class of an algorithm, all you need is to find the fastest growing term in the complexity function of the algorithm. For example, if you have complexity function `f(n)=n^2-10000*n+400`, to find `O(f(n))`, you just have to find the "strongest" term in the function. Why? Because for `n` big enough, only that term dictates the behavior of the entire function. Having said that, it is easy to see that both `f1(n)=n^2-n-4` and `f2(n)=n^2` are in `O(n^2)`. However, they, for the same input size `n`, don't run for the same amount of time.

In your algorithm, if `n=size(arr)`, the `do stuff here` code will run `f(n)=n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1` times. It is easy to see that `f(n)` represents a sum of an arithmetic series, which means `f(n)=n*(n+1)/2`, i.e. `f(n)=0.5*n^2+0.5*n`. If we assume that `do stuff here` is `O(1)`, then your algorithm has `O(n^2)` complexity.

> for i = 0 to size(arr)

I assumed that the loop ends when `i` becomes greater than `size(arr)`, not equal to. However, if the latter is the case, than `f(n)=0.5*n^2-0.5*n`, and it is still in `O(n^2)`. Remember that `O(1),O(n),0(n^2)`,... are complexity classes, and that complexity functions of algorithms are functions that describe, for the input size n, how many steps there is in the algorithm.