# Big O of this sorting algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, complexity-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the complexity of for i: for o = i+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305869/whats-the-complexity-of-for-i-for-o-i1)

I have done the following sorting algorithm for arrays of length 5:

```
int myarray[5] = {2,4,3,5,1};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", myarray[i]);

        int j;
        for (j=i+1; j < 5; j++) 
        {
            int tmp = myarray[i];
            if (myarray[i] > myarray[j]) {
                tmp = myarray[i];
                myarray[i] = myarray[j];
                myarray[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe that the complexity of this sorting algorithm is `O(n*n)` because for each element you compare it with the rest. However, I also notice that for each time we increate in the outer loop, we don't compare with all the rest, but with the rest - i.  What would be the complexity?

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305869/whats-the-complexity-of-for-i-for-o-i1/14305886#14305886)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's still `O(n²)` (or `O(n * n)`, as you wrote). Only the highest order term matters when analysing computational complexity.

Answer (score 5):

You are right:
It's O(1 + 2 + 3... + N)
But mathematically it's just:
= O(n*((n-1)/2))
but that is just:
= O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

You are right, that it is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Here's how to calculate it. On the first iteration, you will look at *n* elements; on the next, *n* - 1, and so on. If you write two copies of that sum, and divide by two, you can pair up the terms, such that you add the first term in the first copy *n* to the last term of the second copy 1, and so on. You wind up with *n* copies of *n* + 1, so the sum winds up being *n* * (*n* + 1) / 2. Big-O only distinguishes asymptotic behavior; the asymptotic behavior is described by the highest order term, without regard to constant factor, which is *n*<sup>2</sup>.

*n* + (*n* - 1) + (*n* - 2) ... + 1
  = 2 * (*n* + (*n* - 1) + (*n* - 2) ... + 1) / 2
  = ((*n* + 1) + (*n* - 1 + 2) + (*n* - 2 + 3) + ... + (1 + *n*)) / 2
  = ((*n* + 1) + (*n* + 1) + ... + (*n* + 1)) / 2
  = *n* * (*n* + 1) / 2
  = 1/2 * *n*<sup>2</sup> + 1/2 * *n*
  = O(*n*<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 2):

This is bubble sort, and it is indeed of complexity O(n^2)

The entire run time of the algorithm can be surmised in the following summation:

> n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n(n+1)/2

Since only the highest order term is of interest in asymptotic analysis, the complexity is O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

The big O notation is *asymptotic*. It means that we overlook constant factors such as `- i`. The complexity of your algorithm is `O(N²)` (see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Performance)).

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is `O(1)`. The `O` notation only makes sense for large inputs, with, where an increase or decrease is not only visible, but relevant.

If you were to extend it, it would be `O(n^2)`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

for multiple loops

n*m*..no.of loops

for above code in worst case its n*n=n^2

BigOh means the max bound.

so the maximum complexity can't be greater then this.

Comment: not only in the worst case, but in any case...

Comment: Agree with you . But bigoh means the max bound so its worst case :).

Answer (score 0):

For 
i=0 it runs for n time

i=1 it runs for n-1 time

i=2 it runs for n-2 time
    ....

```
  So total Sum = (n) + (n-1) + (n-2) + .... + 1
           sum =  (n*n) - (1 + 2 + ...)
               =  n^2   -
```

**So big O complexity = O(n^2)  { upper bound; + or - gets ignored }**