# Big-O complexity of nested loops

Tags: c, complexity-theory, big-o, nested-loops

I'm confused about the complexity of the following (the operation performed inside the inner loop is in constant time):

Pseudocode:

```
for i = 1 to n
   for j = i to n
      for k = i to j
         x := x + 1;
      end for
   end for
end for;
```

Code:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {   
    for(j=i;j<=n;j++) {
        for(k=i;k<=j;k++) {
           x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

O(n^3) ?

Comment: `question-mauvaise.c:4:3: unexpected token '???', did you mean '?'?`

Comment: Can you please format your code properly?  And ideally translate it?

Comment: And honestly, you need to read http://whathaveyoutried.com.  I can think of a dozen ideas here you might have to get started and don't think there is much honor in helping you avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> O(n^3) ???

Yes, even if you don't bother translating your homework from French.

Comment: how i can get O(n^2) ?

Comment: @user2151641 By getting rid one of the loops?

Comment: how i can calcule that with sigma ?

Comment: O( n * n * n) which is O (n^3). The cost is mutliplied cause it's nested. If they were side by side as opposed to nested it'd be O(3n) or O (n) cost. This is basic algorithms 101.

Comment: Are you sure it is O(n^3)? The loops are not starting at 0, nor do all of them go to n?

Comment: @Nashibukasan ["There's a reason asymptotic complexity is called **asymptotic** and not **identical**..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305869/whats-the-complexity-of-for-i-for-o-i1/14305886#14305886)

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks! I was getting confused myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's the product of `O(outer loop in outer loop control) * O(inner loop in inner loop control)`.